# Lottery winner has brain uploaded, then travels in a starship

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for the title of a book / series i read many years ago, i have tried google but i just cant seem to get the search right so any help would be great.

The basis of the story is about a young guy who ends up winning the lotto which allows him to get the best health care and in the end transfer his mind to a computer and travel around on a star ship.  I cannot remember the characters name.  If i remember correctly it was a 2 or 3 book series.  If there are any other details that may help let me know what could be useful.

Again thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How many years ago was "many?"  You might be able to improve this question by checking out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a chance this might be the "[Gateway](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1884)" series by Frederik Pohl.  The first book came out in 1977.

The first book starts with the protagonist winning a lottery which puts the book's plot into motion. Healthcare is purchased, the best is called "Full Medical".

I don't remember the mind transfer into a computer, but IMHO the sequels weren't nearly as good as "Gateway" and I lost interest quickly, so could be a later book.

The series (at least the part I read) mostly deals with humanity's interactions with technology left scattered about the solar system by a race they call the "Heechee", maybe that rings a bell?

Comment: Thank you so very much.. that was it :)

Comment: You're welcome! If you like, please click the gray checkmark by the answer to indicate that it's correct.

Comment: I will. just waiting on the timer to end, says 5 more mins before i can mark it answered.

Comment: Thank you! And welcome to sf stack exchange